# Primitive and Object comparison with == operator

Tags: java, comparison, long-integer

I am wondering what is the internal Java behaviour for the next snippet:

```
Long a = 123L;
long b = 123;
System.out.println("a equals b?: " + (a == b));
```

The result is `true` although comparing two `Long` objects would be `false` (because it compares their reference). It is Java converting `Long` object into its primitive value because detects `==` operator against another primitive object?

Comment: "although comparing two Long objects would be false because of it compares their reference" - in this case even if it boxed, it would be true due to the caching of boxed objects for small numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It is Java converting Long object into its primitive value because detects == operator against another primitive object?

Yes. One of the operands is a primitive type and the other operand is convertible to a primitive by unboxing.

JLS [section 15.21.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) says (emphasis mine):

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and **may perform unboxing conversion** (§5.1.8).

Also, it is important to note that reference equality is only performed if both operands are objects. JLS [section 15.21.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3) says:

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type, then the operation is object equality.

Answer (score 2):

From [the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html):

> **Autoboxing and Unboxing**
>
> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes
>   between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper
>   classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a
>   Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is
>   called unboxing.
>
> Here is the simplest example of autoboxing:
>
> ```
> Character ch = 'a';
> ```
>
> The rest of the examples in this section use generics. If you are not
>   yet familiar with the syntax of generics, see the Generics (Updated)
>   lesson.
>
> Consider the following code:
>
> ```
> List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
> for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 2)
>     li.add(i);
> ```
>
> Although you add the int values as primitive types, rather than
>   Integer objects, to li, the code compiles. Because li is a list of
>   Integer objects, not a list of int values, you may wonder why the Java
>   compiler does not issue a compile-time error. The compiler does not
>   generate an error because it creates an Integer object from i and adds
>   the object to li. Thus, the compiler converts the previous code to the
>   following at runtime:
>
> ```
> List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
> for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 2)
>     li.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
> ```
>
> Converting a primitive value (an int, for example) into an object of
>   the corresponding wrapper class (Integer) is called autoboxing. The
>   Java compiler applies autoboxing when a primitive value is:
>
> - Passed as a parameter to a method that expects an object of the
>     corresponding wrapper class.
> - Assigned to a variable of the
>     corresponding wrapper class.
>     Consider the following method:
>
>   public static int sumEven(List li) {
>         int sum = 0;
>         for (Integer i: li)
>             if (i % 2 == 0)
>                 sum += i;
>             return sum;
>     }
>
> Because the remainder (%) and unary plus (+=) operators do not apply
>   to Integer objects, you may wonder why the Java compiler compiles the
>   method without issuing any errors. The compiler does not generate an
>   error because it invokes the intValue method to convert an Integer to
>   an int at runtime:
>
> ```
> public static int sumEven(List<Integer> li) {
>     int sum = 0;
>     for (Integer i : li)
>         if (i.intValue() % 2 == 0)
>             sum += i.intValue();
>         return sum;
> }
> ```
>
> Converting an object of a wrapper type (Integer) to its corresponding
>   primitive (int) value is called unboxing. The Java compiler applies
>   unboxing when an object of a wrapper class is:
>
> - Passed as a parameter to a method that expects a value of the    corresponding primitive type.
> - Assigned to a variable of the corresponding primitive type.